# Should I restandardize training data during retraining?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, keras

I am running a simple keras deep learning which i will train once and then retrain every month as new data becomes available.

My data is made up of monetary values so i will first standardize my data using StandardScaler() however once new data comes in and i want to retrain can i use the same StandardScaler object? Because lets assume that the new data has a maximum datapoint higher than my current maximum and will thus alter the entire dataset standardization.

Should i re-standardize or can i use the same standardization for the new data?

Comment: When you retrain an existing model, I would use the same scaler as used for initial training. In case the new (training) data will have values larger then the original (scaled) data, the value will simply be greater one. This is not a problem, since you only want to prevent „extreme“ fluctuation in absolute values to make sure the modell „learns“ well. In case there are many values which are much larger then values in the original scaled data, you could run into trouble. This will likely result in bad convergence and/or poor model performance.

Comment: As the goal of standardisation is to have all the features on the same scale, I would suggest to re-standardize, to be sure of it. Otherwise if a data become bigger it may impact prediction too much.